# Using data.table::fwrite() to write .txt files — is.list(x) is not TRUE

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to replace the base R function `write.table()` with `data.table::fwrite()` to speed up writing, but the function complains that 
`is.list(x) is not TRUE`.

What is problem with the input I'm providing that `fwrite()` expects, but `write.table()` silently accepts?

```r
sample_txt <- c("Obligationenrecht\n4 Die Bankenkommission kann unter den Voraussetzungen von Absatz 2 die\nAnwendung der vom Bundesrat anerkannten Standards zur Rechnungslegung im\nBereich der Banken einschränken.\n9. Börsengesetz vom 24. März 199530\nArt. 16          Rechnungslegung\n1 Die Bestimmungen des Bankengesetzes vom 8. November 193431 über die\nRechnungslegung für Banken gelten sinngemäss auch für Effektenhändler.\n2 Der Bundesrat kann von den Bestimmungen nach Absatz 1 abweichen, wenn")

write.table(
  sample_txt,
  file = here::here("test.txt"),
  sep = "\t",
  row.names = FALSE,
  col.names = FALSE
)

data.table::fwrite(
  sample_txt,
  file = here::here("test.txt"),
  sep = ";",
  col.names = FALSE,
  row.names = FALSE
)
#> Error in data.table::fwrite(sample_txt, file = here::here("test.txt"), : is.list(x) is not TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You don't have tabular data. Why don't you simply use write()? Anyway, wrap your data in data.table() if you insist on using fwrite().

Comment: it works with `sample_txt <- list(...)`

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your suggestion! I was doing some benchmarking, that's why I wanted to get this particular solution to work — `write()` is both faster and more suitable in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @s.brunel and @Roland, here are two working solutions:

```r
sample_txt <- c("Obligationenrecht\n4 Die Bankenkommission kann unter den Voraussetzungen von Absatz 2 die\nAnwendung der vom Bundesrat anerkannten Standards zur Rechnungslegung im\nBereich der Banken einschränken.\n9. Börsengesetz vom 24. März 199530\nArt. 16          Rechnungslegung\n1 Die Bestimmungen des Bankengesetzes vom 8. November 193431 über die\nRechnungslegung für Banken gelten sinngemäss auch für Effektenhändler.\n2 Der Bundesrat kann von den Bestimmungen nach Absatz 1 abweichen, wenn")

# solution 1 
data.table::fwrite(
  x = data.table::data.table(sample_txt),
  file = here::here("test.txt"),
  sep = ";",
  col.names = FALSE,
  row.names = FALSE
)

# solution 2 

data.table::fwrite(
  x = list(sample_txt),
  file = here::here("test.txt"),
  sep = ";",
  col.names = FALSE,
  row.names = FALSE
)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>