# Merge ten CSV files, without duplication of the first column

Tags: python, r, database, csv, merge

I have two different CSV files. They each have two columns. The first column in the files is always the same.
I need a python or R code to merge these CVS files into one, without duplicating the first column. So, in the end, the merged CSV file should have eleven columns.

**I want to do this:**

**I have these files:**

**file1.CSV with two columns A and B**

**file2.CSV with two columns A and C**

**Final out put:**

**file3.CSV with three columns A and B and C**

I want to do like this:

```
File 1: Input
A         B 
2007-1    100  
2007-1    4   
2007-1    30  
2007-1    22   
2007-1    13   
2007-1    12   

File 2: Input
A         B
2007-1    33  
2007-1    56   
2007-1    34  
2007-1    3   
2007-1    55   
2007-1    68   

Desire output
A         B     C
2007-1    33    100
2007-1    56    4
2007-1    34    30
2007-1    3     22
2007-1    55    13
2007-1    68    12
```

Answer (score 0):

In R something like the code below could work. Untested, since there are no data.

```
csv_filenames <- c('path/to/your/first_csv_file.csv', 
                   'path/to/your/second_csv_file.csv')
df_list <- lapply(csv_filenames, read.csv)
```

After reading in the data into one list of data.frames, with the posted data `Reduce/merge` will give the following cartesian product of the data.frames.

```r
Reduce(\(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "A"), df_list)
#>         A   B  C
#> 1  2007-1 100 33
#> 2  2007-1 100 56
#> 3  2007-1 100 34
#> 4  2007-1 100  3
#> 5  2007-1 100 55
#> 6  2007-1 100 68
#> 7  2007-1   4 33
#> 8  2007-1   4 56
#> 9  2007-1   4 34
#> 10 2007-1   4  3
#> 11 2007-1   4 55
#> 12 2007-1   4 68
#> 13 2007-1  30 33
#> 14 2007-1  30 56
#> 15 2007-1  30 34
#> 16 2007-1  30  3
#> 17 2007-1  30 55
#> 18 2007-1  30 68
#> 19 2007-1  22 33
#> 20 2007-1  22 56
#> 21 2007-1  22 34
#> 22 2007-1  22  3
#> 23 2007-1  22 55
#> 24 2007-1  22 68
#> 25 2007-1  13 33
#> 26 2007-1  13 56
#> 27 2007-1  13 34
#> 28 2007-1  13  3
#> 29 2007-1  13 55
#> 30 2007-1  13 68
#> 31 2007-1  12 33
#> 32 2007-1  12 56
#> 33 2007-1  12 34
#> 34 2007-1  12  3
#> 35 2007-1  12 55
#> 36 2007-1  12 68
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Another option with `merge` is to create an `id` column first, assigning the row names to it and join the data by two columns, the newly created one and column `"A"`.

```r
df_list <- lapply(df_list, \(x) {
  x$id <- row.names(x)
  x[c(3, 1, 2)]
})
Reduce(\(x, y) merge(x, y), df_list)[-1]
#>        A   B  C
#> 1 2007-1 100 33
#> 2 2007-1   4 56
#> 3 2007-1  30 34
#> 4 2007-1  22  3
#> 5 2007-1  13 55
#> 6 2007-1  12 68
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Maybe the merge operation wanted is in fact a binding by columns, removing the first column of each of the 2nd, etc, data.frames in order not to repeat column `"A"`.

```r
Reduce(\(x, y) cbind(x, y[-1]), df_list)
#>        A   B  C
#> 1 2007-1 100 33
#> 2 2007-1   4 56
#> 3 2007-1  30 34
#> 4 2007-1  22  3
#> 5 2007-1  13 55
#> 6 2007-1  12 68
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I used this code. now my final output is a CSV file with a one column. 
I want do like this:
I have these files:
file1.CSV with two columns A and B
file2.CSV with two columns A and C

Final out put:
file3.CSV with two columns A and B and C

Comment: @misoo Can you post sample data? `dput(head(df1))`, `dput(head(df2))`, `dput(head(df3))` would be enough.

Comment: sure, where do you want me to upload it?

Comment: @misoo Don't need to upload, just post the output of those R instructions in the question.

Comment: I updated the question. your code was like removing thee first column and merged data after each other in the same column.

Comment: I used the updated version. my output is exactly the same as one of the CSV files. so it has columns A and B and not C.

Comment: @misoo I cannot reproduce your output. See now, after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this would be to append all csv files and then drop the duplicates (assuming the column names are same ex: timestamp) while keeping the first column.

```
 from google.colab import drive
 drive.mount('/content/drive')
 #create a folder and name it csv-merge
 #add your csv files in it
 %cd '/content/drive/My Drive/csv-merge/'

 import glob
 # list all csv files only
 csv_files = glob.glob('*.{}'.format('csv'))
 print(csv_files) #this will list out all the csv files
 >>output : ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']

 import pandas as pd 
 df_csv_append = pd.DataFrame() 
 #append the CSV files
 for file in csv_files:
     df = pd.read_csv(file)
     df_csv_append = df_csv_append.append(df, ignore_index=True)
     df_csv_append
      df_csv_append.to_csv('appended.csv')
      #df = df.drop_duplicates('column_name', keep='last')`
```

`

Comment: Thanks, where I can add my files' path and my file's name?
i have two CSV files.

Comment: I have added the changes in the above code, the variable csv_files will have a list of the csv files. in your case two csv files. @misoo

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not know how to add my path and my CSV files name. i want to run the code in COLAB

Comment: Include the csv files in drive folder. In a cell, run the first three lines and see if its displaying your two csv file names.  To add path to colab, use these lines - 'from google.colab import drive`  `drive.mount('/content/drive')`  `%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/your folder name'` and then run the code mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye I have the solution in R, using the tidyverse and data.table packages.

For the code to work, you need to create a folder with only your .csv files.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

file_names<-list.files("path/to/your/")

df_list=file_names%>% map(~{
  return(fread(paste0("path/to/your/",.x),colClasses = 'character'))
}) 

df= df_list %>% purrr::reduce(dplyr::left_join, by = 'First_col_name')

fwrite(df,'path/to/your/merged_csv_file.csv')
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Error in fwrite(df, "~/Desktop/Stats/m/merged_2csv_file.csv") : 


  is.list(x) is not TRUE

Comment: Maybe try adding `sep=",",dec="."` in the fread and fwrite (or whatever is used to separate columns and decimals in your original .csv files), or try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631040/using-data-tablefwrite-to-write-txt-files-is-listx-is-not-true)